# jquery mouseent/leave to make div appears

Tags: jquery, html, mouseenter

I am looking to hover over my list item and have an effect similar to something like facebook chat is my best example..I am able to get the first div to appear but I believe this may be a selector issue because I cant get the rest working properly

**html**

```
<ul id="menu_seo" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-seo"><span class="arrowout1"></span>SEO</li>
    <li id="menu-siteaudits"><span class="arrowout2"></span>Site Audits </li>
    <li id="menu-linkbuilding"><span class="arrowout3"></span>Link-Building</li>
    <li id="menu-localseo"><span class="arrowout4"></span>Local SEO</li>
</ul>
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="menu-seo-desc">
        <p>SEO management begins with a full website diagnosis of current web strategy Adjustments are made to improve your site's ability to rank higher on search engines and draw more traffic </p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-seo-desc2">
        <p>Usability & site architecture review, Search Engine accessibility and indexing, Keyword research & targeting and Conversion rate optimization </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```css
#menu-seo-desc {
    height: 125px;
    width: 210px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #CCC #E8E8E8 #E8E8E8 #CCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 2px 0px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 2px 0px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 2px 1px #888;
    position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    left: 350px;
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu_seo').on('#menu-seo', {
        'mouseenter': function() {
            $('#menu-seo-desc').fadeIn(600);
            $('#menu-seo-desc2').fadeIn(600);
        },
        'mouseleave': function() {
            $('#menu-seo-desc').fadeOut(300);
            $('#menu-seo-desc2').fadeOut(300);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is a class selector, use `#` instead to get it as `id`.

Change `$('.menu-seo-desc')` to `$('#menu-seo-desc')` 
And `$('.menu-seo-desc').fadeOut(300);` to `$('#menu-seo-desc').fadeOut(300);`

*Suggestion*:
You can bind multiple events to the same element, like the following.

```
$('#menu_seo').on('#menu-seo', {
    'mouseenter': function() {
        $('#menu-seo-desc').fadeIn(600);
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
        $('#menu-seo-desc').fadeOut(300);
    }
});
```

**Update**:

```
// bind mouseenter and mouseleave for both selectors
$('#menu-seo, #menu-siteaudits').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    // get the related container
    $element = $(this).is('#menu-seo') ? $('#menu-seo-desc') : $('#menu-seo-desc2');
    // execute the action according to the event
    if(e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $element.fadeIn(600);
    } else {
        $element.fadeOut(300);
    }
});
```

Comment: my problem is I am not getting the next div menu-seo-desc2 to appear when i hover site audits..i have a div for each one of those <li>

Comment: @Blake You didn't bind the event to do it.

Comment: so adding this $('#menu_seo').on('#menu-seo', {
        'mouseenter': function() {
        $('#menu-seo-desc').fadeIn(600);
  $('#menu-seo-desc2').fadeIn(600); to the top and bottom will solve that?
  
  
      },

Comment: sorry i added it to my previous script up top to make it more clear

Comment: ok perfect, and so I have two more divs for each one of those li items..how do i add those to that since that is just a true false..this is the effect im looking for though

Comment: @Blake You can add to the selectors separated by `,`. Like I do to bind event for both `li`s. `$('#menu-seo, #menu-siteaudits')`

Comment: hey quick question, is there a method to use to set a delay so that if someone hovers and goes off the div wont appear..just to avoid any kind of glitches

Comment: @Blake Search for hoverintent. It's a lib that do it.

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/eveluf/1/edit)*

```
  $('#menu-seo').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function( e ){
    var mEnt = (e.type=='mouseenter');
    $('#menu-seo-desc').stop().fadeTo(600, mEnt?1:0 );
  });
```

- `mEnt` will return a *Boolean* true//false depending on the `e` *event type*.
- Ternary operator will do `mEnt?[true]:[false]` and respectively `fadeTo([time], [1/or/0])`
- Additionally the selector is: `$('#menu-seo-desc')`